# Center a paragraph with specific width

Tags: html, css

How can I horizontally center this paragraph within its parent div? I need the paragraph to have a width of 15ch, but applying that width pushes it to the left because it no longer implicitly takes up 100% of the div.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15ch;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This 1 sentence paragraph should be centered.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't paste fiddles here .. SO has it's own snippet tool ..

Comment: You might have a look at [ask] and take the [tour]. Local demonstrations are expected when appropriate, such as here. Also don't post "thanks" comments.

Comment: Please see [This Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle) as well -- *"Stack Overflow does not want you to just post a JSFiddle link"* -- This is not my preference ... This is the accepted and approved method set forth by SO community itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin:auto` to your `<p>` tag:

```css
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    margin:auto;
    width: 15ch;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>This 1 sentence paragraph should be centered.</p>
</div>
```